# How can I make nats:Listener use a custom ConnectionConfiguration object in Ballerina?

Tags: java, service, ballerina

I am using the code provided on the official project page at https://ballerina.io/learn/by-example/nats-basic-sub/.

The code looks like this:

```
    import ballerina/log;
    import ballerinax/nats;

    public type Order record {
        int orderId;
        string productName;
        decimal price;
        boolean isValid;
    };

    // Binds the consumer to listen to the messages published to the 'orders.valid' subject.
    service "orders.valid" on new nats:Listener(nats:DEFAULT_URL) {

        remote function onMessage(Order 'order) returns error? {
            if 'order.isValid {
                log:printInfo(string `Received valid order for ${'order.productName}`);
            }
        }
    }
```

I need to annotate or pass a ConnectionConfiguration object to the service's listener so that I can modify the nats:RetryConfig object. My goal is to make the service keep trying to connect to the NATS server every 5 seconds without interruption if the NATS server becomes unavailable until the NATS server becomes available again. I think this can be achieved by setting maxReconnect to -1 and reconnectWait to 5.

I looked for some helpers and/or callbacks in the service code but I think it is not the right approach.

How can I do this? Can it be done with any annotations on the service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify the code to pass the `ConnectionConfiguration` record to the listener initialisation with the values `maxReconnect` and `reconnectWait` as given below.

```
import ballerina/log;
import ballerinax/nats;

public type Order record {
    int orderId;
    string productName;
    decimal price;
    boolean isValid;
};

final nats:ConnectionConfiguration & readonly config = {
    retryConfig: {maxReconnect: -1, reconnectWait: 5}
};

service "orders.valid" on new nats:Listener(nats:DEFAULT_URL, config) {

    remote function onMessage(Order 'order) returns error? {
        if 'order.isValid {
            log:printInfo(string `Received valid order for ${'order.productName}`);
        }
    }
}
```

OR

```
import ballerina/log;
import ballerinax/nats;

public type Order record {
    int orderId;
    string productName;
    decimal price;
    boolean isValid;
};

service "orders.valid" on new nats:Listener(nats:DEFAULT_URL, {retryConfig: {maxReconnect: -1, reconnectWait: 5}}) {

    remote function onMessage(Order 'order) returns error? {
        if 'order.isValid {
            log:printInfo(string `Received valid order for ${'order.productName}`);
        }
    }
}
```